# error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/my.cnf': Invalid argument

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 22.04, mariadb

When running apt upgrade on my Ubuntu 22.04.1 server I get an error that prevents all upgrades.  After a few weeks of googling I'm at a loss.  Does anyone else recognize the cause?

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up mariadb-common (1:10.6.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/my.cnf': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-common (--configure):
 installed mariadb-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error 
exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of [`mariadb-common`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mariadb-common), there is a symbolic link file named `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf` that the Ubuntu alternatives system use:

```bash
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/my.cnf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Mar 11 10:39 /etc/alternatives/my.cnf -> /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf
```

That file should be only managed by the Ubuntu alternatives system(*using the [`update-alternatives`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) command*) ... Handling that file otherwise will break it and render it unidentifiable/unusable by the Ubuntu alternatives system ... It appears that is what happened in your case ... Hence the error:

> update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file
> '/etc/alternatives/my.cnf': Invalid argument

To solve this remove the existing symbolic link/file like so:

```bash
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
```

Then recreate it the right way(*or in your case `sudo apt upgrade` will do*) like so:

```bash
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mariadb-common
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
```