# Error 'update-initramfs: 175: awk: Too many levels of symbolic links' when using APT

Tags: apt, symbolic-link, initramfs

I'm on Ubuntu 22.10, when trying to run `apt` or `apt-get` with `{install|remove|auto-remove}` I got the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu17) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu17) ...
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 175: awk: Too many levels of symbolic links
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned 
error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

the error message shows:

```
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 175: awk: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

so I tried to run `update-initramfs` separately

```
ya22y@IYB:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 175: awk: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

to ensure file permissions

```
    ya22y@IYB:~$ stat ../../usr/sbin/update-initramfs
  File: ../../usr/sbin/update-initramfs
  Size: 6906        Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 803h/2051d  Inode: 6553706     Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

as far as I know, there's an infinite loop of file A referencing to file B leading to this error. I checked to update-initramfs code but I have no clue how to resolve this error.

EDIT
I checked `update-initramfs` again, the error source was **boot_opts**

```
ro_boot_check()
{
        # check irrelevant inside of a chroot
        if [ ! -r /proc/mounts ] || ischroot; then
                return 0
        fi

        #shellcheck disable=SC1004
        boot_opts=$(awk '/boot/{if ((match($4, /^ro/) || match($4, /,ro/)) \
                && $2 == "/boot") print "ro"}' /proc/mounts)

        if [ -n "${boot_opts}" ]; then
                echo "W: /boot is ro mounted." >&2
                echo "W: update-initramfs: Not updating ${initramfs}" >&2
                exit 0
        fi
}
```

boot directory

```
ya22y@IYB:~$ ls ../../boot
config-5.19.0-35-generic      memtest86+.elf
efi                           memtest86+_multiboot.bin
grub                          System.map-5.19.0-35-generic
initrd.img                    vmlinuz
initrd.img-5.19.0-35-generic  vmlinuz-5.19.0-35-generic
memtest86+.bin
```

I tried

```
awk
Command 'awk' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gawk          # version 1:5.1.0-1build3, or
sudo apt install mawk          # version 1.3.4.20200120-3.1
sudo apt install original-awk  # version 2018-08-27-1
```

as @Bodo mentionned

```
ya22y@IYB:~$ ls -l ../../usr/bin/awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 mars   6 23:17 ../../usr/bin/awk -> /usr/bin/awk
```

also tried

```
sudo sh -c 'awk'
sh: 1: awk: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

so i decided to change `awk` to `mawk` inside `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs`

```
 
 #shellcheck disable=SC1004
       #changing awk to mawk 
       boot_opts=$(mawk '/boot/{if ((match($4, /^ro/) || match($4, /,ro/)) \
                && $2 == "/boot") print "ro"}' /proc/mounts)
```

checking

```
ya22y@IYB:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-35-generic
ya22y@IYB:~$
```

Now i got a different error

```
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu17) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up original-awk (2018-08-27-1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/awk': Too many levels of 
symbolic links
dpkg: error processing package original-awk (--configure):
 installed original-awk package post-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 2
```

Mainly, the `awk` link is broken, how can i repaire that ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the output of `type awk`. This will print something like `awk is /usr/bin/awk`. Show the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/awk` (or whatever the `type` command printed). I would expect something like ...`/usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk`. Repeat with the link target to get soemthing like ...`/etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk`. Show all this in your question. It could also be a symlink loop for some of the directories involved.

Comment: Please add details how you "found that awk is not found". Copy&paste the command you used and the resulting output. I suspect that the shell found a symlink loop when it tried to execute `awk` in `boot_opts=$(awk '...' /proc/mounts)`. If `type awk` shows `awk: not found` retry with `sudo type awk`.

Comment: @Bodo `type` is a shell builtin - you'd need something like `sudo sh -c 'type awk'`

Comment: @Bodo @steeldriver thanks for mentionning, i've edited my question, ```awk`` link is broken as the link target is ```/usr/bin/awk`` and the parent folder is ```/usr/bin/``` so its looping and thats what causing the error. How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply **deleting** the broken link will resolve the problem.

```
ya22y@IYB:/usr/bin$ sudo rm awk
```

(Edit)

Then created a new link

`sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/awk /usr/bin/awk`

Comment: This will fix remove the recursive link, but probably there should be a different link. You could try to reinstall the `gawk` package. If there is correct link `/etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk` (or to a different alternative), you can create a link `/usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk` by `sudo ln -s /etc/alternatives/awk /usr/bin/awk` after deleting the broken link.

Comment: Actually i forget to mention, after removing the recursive link and running apt one more time, for some reason ```/usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk``` was created automatically.

Comment: Manually altering files under `/etc/alternatives/` will break the Ubuntu Alternatives system and result in errors ... Please see for example: [error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/my.cnf': Invalid argument](https://askubuntu.com/q/1458756/968501) @Bodo

Comment: @Raffa I did not propose to modify anything **in** `/etc/alternatives` but to re-create a link pointing **to** it.

Comment: @Bodo I know ... However, this includes `/usr/bin/awk` as well ... I thought I made it clear the first time ... Given the error message provided in the question `update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/bin/awk' ...` ... But, clearly, I didn't :-) ... So, kindly see my updated answer now ... It should be clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Manually altering files under `/etc/alternatives/` will break the Ubuntu Alternatives system and result in errors ... Please see for example: [error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/my.cnf': Invalid argument](https://askubuntu.com/q/1458756/968501)

The default `awk` variant installed on Ubuntu is `mawk` ... You should be able to, correctly, fix the broken/unusable file/link for `awk` under `/etc/alternatives/` by removing it first, like so:

```bash
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/awk
```

Then, recreating it the right way, like so:

```bash
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mawk
```

**Notice**: If `gawk` is installed on your system, then it will take precedence and that link should read:

```bash
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 17 11:44 /etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
```

or otherwise, it should read:

```bash
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 17 11:44 /etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/mawk
```

**Also notice**: That `/usr/bin/awk` is merely a symbolic link managed by the Ubuntu Alternatives system as well that leads back to `/etc/alternatives/awk` and it should be like:

```bash
$ ls -l /usr/bin/awk 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jan  8  2022 /usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk
```

So, you shouldn't manually alter that one either or you will need to fix both by removing them first, like so:

```bash
$ sudo rm /etc/alternatives/awk /usr/bin/awk
```

Then, recreate them both the right way like so:

```bash
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mawk
```

And, afterwords, they should be fixed and look something like this:

```bash
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/awk /usr/bin/awk 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Mar 17 14:02 /etc/alternatives/awk -> /usr/bin/gawk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar 17 14:02 /usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk
```